# angular.js Routing doesn't work on the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ngRoute in my site, it work well on my computer (local) but on the server routing doesn't work. On my computer all my files are html, on the server i rename them as php. How can i fix it?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "pages/main.php",
        controller: 'oneCtrl'
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "pages/about.php"
    })
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl : "pages/news.php"
    })
});
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Open your dev tools and look at the network requests. What is being requested, and what fails? For what reason?  Now look at your server logs - are there any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I have some progress here :) at first i dounload angular.js file and put on the server - it doesn't work, but now i link to hosted libraries it works, Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined Second error routes.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: Looks like you not include angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error messages you're getting (as you said in the comments), the Angular library is not being loaded.  Double-check the URL.  Also in the browser dev tools, check the Network tab and see what error it shows.  Probably a `404 not found`.

After checking your website and the line where you said the error was occurring (line 156 of `route.js`), change your code to this:

```
    $('.counter-one span').eq(0).html(value1 + '&nbsp;');
    $('.counter-two span').eq(0).html(value2 + '&nbsp;');
```

You did a search/replace for "html" to "php" but that also replaced the jQuery `html()` command.  Just fix these two lines and you should be good.

Comment: You need to make sure that Angular can load.  The quickest way to test/fix this is to use an external Angular library such as `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js`. If you want to include the JS file on your server, make sure it's in the correct directory and that it has the right permissions.

Comment: some controllers don't work error routes.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).eq(...).php is not a function

Comment: I see your problem.  You did a search/replace for "html" -> "php" which changed your URLs but it also changed your jQuery code.  See my updated answer where I'll post the fix.